# Hibernate + SQL Azure = Cannot find data type boolean

Tags: hibernate, azure, azure-sql-database

i am using hbm2ddl.auto=create to generate the schema in a SQL Azure database with hibernate.
This fails when using a Boolean or boolean type with an "Cannot find data type boolean." exception.

This might be related to the used dialect "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" and this [Bug report](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-6420?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugins.jira-github-connector-plugin%3agithub-commits-tabpanel). I am using Hibernate-core 4.1.3 and therefore this bug should be resolved.

Can somebody help me to fix this problem?

Comment: I am making progress: While using the SQLServer2008Dialect, the schema is created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your dialect to `org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect` if your database version is SQLServer 2008

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, SQL Server doesn’t have a Boolean data type, please try to use the bit data type.

Comment: You are right. The SQLServer2008Dialect maps the boolean data type to the bit data type. Therefore this dialect is a solution to this problem, whereat i do not know if it is perfectly suitable for sql azure.

Comment: Sebastian, I also don't know if this is correct for Azure.  However, it pointed me in the right direction for 2008 (I didn't realize there was a separate dialect for 2008).  If you put that as an answer, I'll upvote it.